# Creating list per participant ID with 3 dataframes for each participant in RStudio

Tags: r

I'm super new to R and RStudio, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question!

I have an excel file with 3 columns: PID (participant ID), Cond, Time and Correct. Each PID has 150 trials (so 150 different reaction times to 3 different conditions, and their responses are either correct or incorrect) (see image of Excel file).

I want to import these into RStudio, but organise the data so that each PID is a single list. Within each PID list, I want 3 dataframes which include the respective condition, time and correct response for that specific PID.

Here is what I want the data to LOOK like in RStudio (see the image of example data in R).

Does anyone know how I can rearrange the data to look like this after I have read in the .csv file into R Studio?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Picture of what I WANT the data to look like once it's organised

[image]

Picture of how my data is organised as a .csv file

[image]

Comment: You should not add data as images. We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `split` and `lapply` to get data in your required form.

```
df <- data.frame(PID = rep(1:4, each = 3), Cond = sample(3, 12, replace = TRUE),
                 Time = rnorm(12), Correct = sample(2, 12, replace = TRUE))

result <- lapply(split(df, df$PID), function(x) as.list(x[-1]))
View(result)
```

[image]